# Объединение объектов в один div

Tags: php, codeigniter

Имеется вывод массива объектов:

```
<?php $compare = 0; ?>

<?php foreach($arr as $key => $value): ?>

            <?php if($compare != $value['id_storage']): ?>

            <ul class="box box-main box-<?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?>">
                <div class="box-main-wrapper" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
                    <li><?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['category_name']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['name_storage']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['mount']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['price']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['exp_date']); ?></li>
                    <li><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-details" value="Подробнее" style="align-self: center;"></li>
                    <?php  $compare = $value['id_storage']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="sub-box-wrapper"></div>
            </ul>

            <?php else: ?>
                <ul class="hide box sub-box sub-box-<?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?>">
                    <li><?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['category_name']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['name_storage']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['mount']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['price']); ?></li>
                    <li><?php echo ($value['exp_date']); ?></li>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>

            <?php endif ?>
```

При таком выводе в DOM-дереве ul с классом **box-main** создается первым, а ul с классом **sub-box** отдельно и ниже, чем  ul с классом box-main. Как генерировать ul с классом sub-box внутри box-main, а точнее, внутри **sub-box-wrapper** ? Первый объект с 'id_storage' записывается в 'box-main', а остальные объекты с таким же 'id_storage' -  в 'sub-box'.

Пример массива объектов $arr:

```
`Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 2.22222e25
        [mount] => 2
        [exp_date] => 0000-00-00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 800
        [mount] => 350
        [exp_date] => 2017-09-04
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 400
        [mount] => 8
        [exp_date] => 2017-09-01
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 0
        [mount] => 0
        [exp_date] => 0000-00-00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 789
        [mount] => 136
        [exp_date] => 2018-09-10
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 0
        [mount] => 0
        [exp_date] => 0000-00-00
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 0
        [mount] => 0
        [exp_date] => 0000-00-00
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 32313
        [mount] => 1134
        [exp_date] => 2018-09-10
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 0
        [mount] => 0
        [exp_date] => 0000-00-00
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 1578
        [mount] => 16534
        [exp_date] => 2018-09-10
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 400
        [mount] => 20
        [exp_date] => 2017-09-02
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 500
        [mount] => 200
        [exp_date] => 2017-09-03
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 20
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => MSI Z370 Gaming Plus (s1151, Intel Z370, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 0
        [mount] => 0
        [exp_date] => 0000-00-00
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 21
        [category_name] => Motherboard
        [name_storage] => Asus M5A78L-M LX3 (sAM3+, AMD 760G, PCI-Ex16)
        [price] => 123
        [mount] => 1
        [exp_date] => 2018-03-03
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 22
        [category_name] => CPU
        [name_storage] => Intel Core i7-8700K 3.7GHz/8GT/s/12MB
        [price] => 777
        [mount] => 459
        [exp_date] => 2018-09-30
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 22
        [category_name] => CPU
        [name_storage] => Intel Core i7-8700K 3.7GHz/8GT/s/12MB
        [price] => 123123
        [mount] => 11
        [exp_date] => 2018-09-10
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 22
        [category_name] => CPU
        [name_storage] => Intel Core i7-8700K 3.7GHz/8GT/s/12MB
        [price] => 1121
        [mount] => 22
        [exp_date] => 2018-03-09
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 23
        [category_name] => CPU
        [name_storage] => Intel Pentium G4500 3.5GHz/8GT/s/3MB
        [price] => 999
        [mount] => 111
        [exp_date] => 2018-09-10
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [id_storage] => 24
        [category_name] => Monitor
        [name_storage] => Монитор 24" Samsung S24D300HS
        [price] => 1214440
        [mount] => 1232
        [exp_date] => 2018-01-02
    )
)
```

Comment: 3 раза перечитал, но так и не понял, о чем вопрос

Comment: Сейчас при выполнении кода в else создаются новые ul'ы с классом sub-box ниже ul'а с классом box-main( в Dev Tools это выглядит так:
`<ul class="box box-main box-20"></ul>
<ul class="hide box sub-box sub-box-20"></ul>
<ul class="hide box sub-box sub-box-20"></ul>`). Мне нужно во время выполнение else помещать ul'ы с классом sub-box в div с классом sub-box-wrapper

Comment: Продублируйте в `else` все то, что вам нужно

Comment: `<?php else: ?>
    <ul class="box box-main box-<?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?>">
    <li><?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?></li>
    ...
    <div class="sub-box-wrapper">
                <ul class="hide box sub-box sub-box-<?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?>">
                    <li><?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?></li>
    ....
                </ul>
    <ul class="hide box sub-box sub-box-<?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?>">
                    <li><?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?></li>
     ....
                </ul>
    </div>
    </ul>`

Comment: Если закрывать див до того, как его заполнить, то очевидно, что в нем ничего не будет.

Comment: Как соотносятся заголовок вопроса и его содержание?

Comment: @Igor, то есть вам нужно выводить товары для сравнения. И проверить основной это товар и или для сравнения можно на основании `id_storage`?

Comment: @yuriy-prokopets, если товаров с одинаковым `id_storage` больше 1-го, то все товары с одинаковым id_storage попадают в div sub-box-wrapper, а по клику я их показываю.

Comment: @Igor, я бы предложил изменить структуру исходного массива на такую, которая больше подходит для вывода. Если хотите, то могу написать готовый код.

Comment: Если не трудно, но я подозреваю, что менять структуру массива нельзя. Я искал способ как-то ссылаться на текущий ul с классом box-main и помещать туда остальные объекты с таким же id-storage.

Comment: Изменить структуру массива можно создав новый массив с новой структурой ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменяем структуру исходного массива, чтобы можно было его вывести в один проход:

```
<?php
$formated = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (!array_key_exists($item['id_storage'], $formated)) {
        $formated[$item['id_storage']] = $item;
    } else {
       $formated[$item['id_storage']]['compare'][] = $item;
    }
 }
 ?>
```

А теперь выводим с учетом того, что товары для сравнения у нас помещены в подмассив `compare`:

```
<?php foreach($formated as $value): ?>
     <ul class="box box-main box-<?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?>">
            <div class="box-main-wrapper" style="display: flex; width: 100%;">
                <li><?php echo ($value['id_storage']); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo ($value['category_name']); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo ($value['name_storage']); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo ($value['mount']); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo ($value['price']); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo ($value['exp_date']); ?></li>
                <li><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-details" value="Подробнее" style="align-self: center;"></li>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-box-wrapper">
             <?php if (array_key_exists('compare', $value)): ?>
                  <?php foreach($value['compare'] as $subitem): ?>
                      <ul class="hide box sub-box sub-box-<?php echo $subitem['id_storage']; ?>">
                            <li><?php echo ($subitem['id_storage']); ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo ($subitem['category_name']); ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo ($subitem['name_storage']); ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo ($subitem['mount']); ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo ($subitem['price']); ?></li>
                            <li><?php echo ($subitem['exp_date']); ?></li>
                            <li></li>
                      </ul>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
             <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </ul>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```